# Scope in implementation block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wonder is there any difference between the following code:

First

```
@implementation ViewController {
    AAShareBubbles *shareBubbles;
}

// methods' implementations

@end
```

Second

```
@implementation ViewController

AAShareBubbles *shareBubbles;

// methods' implementations

@end
```

Which one do you prefer and why?

Comment: @Signare What do you mean by "global" and "local" declarations? I just want to make this variable private

Comment: The first is local to the class.  Each instance will get its own copy.  The second is a global variable, and all instances of the class will use the same copy (i.e. there's only one such variable in the app).

Comment: if you want to use shareBubbles instance throughout the class in several methods, then use global declaration and if use of shareBubbles is limited to a particular method then use local declaration.

Comment: The use of *local* and *global* in the other comments is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one: it's an instance variable.

Second one: it's a variable inside your implementation scope, you cannot use as an instance variable.

So they're different.
P/S: I've never used the second one.

Answer (score 0):

First code define Objective-C internal variable, so you can use inside of current implement.

Second define a private global variable in C style. If the same variable name is existed in two or more class this will case of runtime error like following image

[image]